# Dual boot Windows 10 with existing Ubuntu 16.04 in legacy mode

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, windows-10, grub-legacy

Good day. I would like to install Windows 10 in legacy mode along with Ubuntu 16.04. My main OS is Ubuntu 16.04 and already installed with some work data. I would like to add Windows 10 in legacy mode as dual boot. How to go about?

Please help, been searching and all solutions I found are not satisfying. I definitely won't format my Ubuntu since I already have installed all applications I need and some customization and work data.

thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Windows only installs to a primary NTFS formatted partition with the boot flag in BIOS boot with MBR partitioned drives. IF drive is gpt or has used all primary partitions then you cannot install Windows to same drive.

Comment: @oldfred Not true. Windows is pretty good at supporting GPT on EFI.

Comment: OP wants Windows in Legacy mode which then is BIOS/MBR. Windows does work fine with UEFI but then drive must be gpt and only gpt. Ubuntu can be either BIOS or UEFI boot from gpt.